# Count multiple items multiple times in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, formula, countif

I'm trying to produce a bar graph of the number of vehicles stopping each minute over a one hour period. I need a table of mins (1 to 60) vs. number of vehicles to do this.

However, my source data is in the form:

```
Vehicle Arr. Min    Dep. Min    Duration
A       10          12             2
B       19          19             0
C       31          32             1    
D       41          44             3
E       42          42             0
F       54          55             1
```

So in the example above:
Vehicle A needs to be counted under minutes 10, 11 and 12.

Vehicles D and E both need counting for minute 42

I can use COUNTIF or COUNTIFS to count a single instance, but I can't figure out a way to count a vehicle across several minutes.

I'm not worried about identifying individual vehicles.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: do you mean vehicle D needs counting for 41,42,43,44? If no, then I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 60 columns to the right titled 1 ... 60 and have a formula in the rows below them (columes E and further) of the sort:

```
=IF(AND($B2<=E$1;$C2>=E$1);1;0)
```

Then sum up for each minute column and you have your count. I have to say CAPSLOCKs answer works in the newer Excel versions. I recommend using his approach for the neater way you are looking for!

Comment: Hi K_B,thanks. That would work (though with commas rather than semi-colons in the formula).  I thought there might be a neater way of doing it using arrays perhaps, as I've got a quite a bit of data to crunch.

Comment: On top for visualization purposes you could even apply conditional formatting to the field of 1s and 0s, such that the cell fills with a color when its value is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [countifs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) function.

Say you were checking for how many are stopped for minute 3 then you could use

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A7, "<=3", B1:B7, ">=3")
```

and change `A1:A7` with whichever range your Arr. Min is in  and `B1:B7` with whichever range your

Comment: Aparently this IS the neater way available!

Comment: Thanks CAPSLOCK but couldn't get this one to work for me. I think I'd still need to sum everything as with K_B below too?